# Confusion about two-argument method reference

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, method-reference

I am a bit confused about this method reference syntax.

`counter()` expects a `BiFunction` however `HighTemp::lessThanTemp` is a valid argument despite `HighTemp.lessThanTemp()` only taking one argument.

What exactly is happening in the line: `if (f.func(vals[i], v))`?

MCVE:

```
import java.util.function.BiFunction;

class Demo {
  static class HighTemp {
    private int hTemp;

    HighTemp(int ht) { hTemp = ht; }

    boolean lessThanTemp(HighTemp ht2) {
      return hTemp < ht2.hTemp;
    }
  }

  static <T> int counter(T[] vals, BiFunction<T,T,Boolean> f, T v) {
    int count = 0;

    for (int i=0; i < vals.length; i++) {
      if (f.apply(vals[i], v)) { // THIS LINE
        count++;
      }
    }

    return count;
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {    
    HighTemp[] weekDayHighs2 = { new HighTemp(32), new HighTemp(12),
                                 new HighTemp(24), new HighTemp(19),
                                 new HighTemp(18), new HighTemp(12),
                                 new HighTemp(-1), new HighTemp(13) };

    int count = counter(weekDayHighs2, HighTemp::lessThanTemp, new HighTemp(19));
    System.out.println(count + " days had a high of less than 19");
  }
}
```

Comment: Tip: instead of defining your own `MyFunc` interface, use [`BiFunction`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiFunction.html) or its subtype [`BinaryOperator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BinaryOperator.html).

Comment: @dimo414 the compile result is "5 days had a high of less than 19".

I am confused on how does this actually work

Comment: @JimGarrison  the `f.func(vals[i],v)` takes two argument, but isn't it the f.func is referred to `HighTemp::lessThanTemp` , which only take one argument.
`boolean lessThanTemp(HighTemp ht2)`

Comment: Ah, I misread the question. Doesn't the first argument get the `this` reference?  I seem to recall reading that the compiler infers that magically.

Comment: I love interesting well-written questions that challenge me to dig through the documentation and make me learn something new.  Welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the [relevant documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html#type), which notes:

> The equivalent lambda expression for the method reference `String::compareToIgnoreCase` would have the formal parameter list `(String a, String b)`, where `a` and `b` are arbitrary names used to better describe this example. The method reference would invoke the method `a.compareToIgnoreCase(b)`.

In other words, `HighTemp::lessThanTemp` is equivalent to the lambda expression:

```
(a, b) -> a.lessThanTemp(b)
```

Comment: And for reference [JLS 15.13.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13.3).  _If the form is ReferenceType :: [TypeArguments] Identifier.... If the compile-time declaration is an instance method, then the target reference is the first formal parameter of the invocation method_